# Bitrix - отобразить только нужные свойства

Tags: php, битрикс

Здравствуйте, возник такой вопрос - у нас в торговом каталоге в разделах настраиваются свойства товаров в конкретном разделе. Т.е. например, автосигнализации имеют уникальной свойство автозапуск двигателя, а фары - уникальной свойство цветовая температура. Однако, в карточке товара в массиве PROPERTIES мне доступны вообще все свойства - т.е. для автосигнализаций доступно свойство цветовая температура. Как мне отобрать только те свойства, которые настроены для определенного раздела? Т.е. мне нужна та же логика, по которой торговый каталог скрывает часть свойств при редактировании элементов конкретного раздела

Answer (score 2):

Вариант номер раз: используйте массив `DISPLAY_PROPERTIES` - он отвечает за вывод свойств, которые нужно отображать. 
Второй вариант Вам нужно кастомизировать шаблон, а лучше `result_modifier.php` дополнив или изменив стандартный вывод свойств получая для нужного раздела свойства элемента с помощью [`CIBlockProperty::GetList`](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockproperty/getlist.php) или [`CIBlockElement::GetProperty`](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getproperty.php) и передавая их в шаблон, если модифицируете через `result_modifier.php`, но можете и отбирать прямо в `template.php`, но это будет не совсем гуд.

Answer (score 1):

В шаблоне проверяйте на заполненное значение свойства.

```
if ($property['VALUE']) {
    //выводим
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но этот вариант не подходит - т.к. свойства могут быть не заполнены контент-менеджером и необходимо выводить текст "нет данных".
Повторюсь - мне нужна именно та логика, которой пользуется торговый каталог, который скрывает ненужные свойства при правке элементов

Comment: Тогда можно создать к разделам каталога множественное пользовательское поле, содержащее коды свойств для вывода в  разделе.
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=04804